# Why is there a difference between these 2 results?

Tags: c, database, syntax

I am a beginner in C programming language, I don't understand why there is -1 in the 2nd command line. thank you in advance.

1. ```
   printf("The maximum value of UNSIGNED INT = %u\n", UINT_MAX);
   ```

   result: `4294967295`
2. ```
   printf("The maximum value of UNSIGNED INT = %d\n", UINT_MAX);
   ```

   result : `-1` (why?)

Comment: The `%d` format is for plain `int` type, which is *signed*. Mismatching format specifier and argument type (like passing an `unsigned int` argument for the `%d` format) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 5):

`%d` tells `printf` to format an `int` that you pass it. You did not pass it an `int`; you passed it an `unsigned int`. It has no knowledge of that and attempts to work with the data that you passed.

“-1” is a common result because the bits for the maximum `unsigned int` (all bits 1) is the same as the bits used for the two’s complement −1 `int` (also all bits 1). However, when you mismatch format conversions and arguments, a variety of things can go wrong. C was developed as a language for telling the computer what to do in a human-friendly way (using symbol names and arithmetic operations and convenient functions rather than assembly language instructions). This makes it easy to tell the computer to do wrong things. This is unlike other languages that add a lot of rules and software to handle things for you automatically, such as managing types more strictly.